# Should I use the text from request.POST or form.cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

It might sound like a trivial question, but this is quite a battle to me.

For a form, and hit submit, should one uses `form.cleaned_data` to access the form data, or look up in `request.POST`?

The only thing that people usually do with `request.POST` is look up the submit button. But if I created a submit button as a widget, I can also look it up in form.cleaned_data.
The thing is, what about other form data? They are lookup-able in `request.POST` as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Plus you could look up submit button in `request.POST` since its value is determined and thus validated actually.

Answer (score 7):

While you could access request.POST directly , it is better to access form.cleaned_data. This data has not only been validated but will also be converted in to the relevant Python types for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can do for example:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    test = forms.CharField(label='A test label', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder":"Your Placeholder", "rows":6, "cols":45}), max_length=150)


if request.method == "POST":
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_test = form.cleaned_data["test"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You never should use request.POST data to save in database because form.clean_data go through all this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/ and make you data safe to deal with.